# Why does external-graphic scale-down-to-fit not work when height specified by percentage?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Suppose I have an image "tall.png" which is too tall for the block that it is being placed in.  I would like the image to automatically scale down to fit into the parent block.

A simple example of what I mean:

```
<fo:block-container height="10cm" width="10cm" border="solid 0.5px black">
  <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic src="tall.png"
       content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit"
       width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </fo:block>    
</fo:block-container>
```

The above code doesn't seem to work.  The resulting PDF shows the image spilling out of the block-container.  On the other hand, if I do this...

```
<fo:block-container height="10cm" width="10cm" border="solid 0.5px black">
  <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic src="tall.png"
       content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit"
       width="10cm" height="10cm"/>
  </fo:block>    
</fo:block-container>
```

That seems to work.  This surprises me since the height property should refer to the height of the containing block when you use percentages (http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_height.asp).    That makes me think that using 100% and using 10cm in my example should be exactly the same, but they don't produce the same result.

For the actual problem that I am trying to solve, I can't hardcode the width and height for the external-graphic.  I need it to just stay within the height/width of its parent block, whatever that might be.  Any idea how to accomplish that?